# How can I replace data from a table with data of another table, similar to a vlookup from Excel?

Tags: sql, sas

Sorry in advance for my bad English.

Using SAS, I'm trying to substitute data from one table, let's call it t1. To substitute, I'm comparing t1 column 1 and t2 column 1. If I have a match, I'd like to use t2 column 2 value.

Table 1 has lots of columns, and the data in the relevant column can be repeated. Table 2 has only two columns, the first one has only unique values, and will be compared to table 1. I will, after that, use values of the second column.

For some reason, I'm generating a cartesian product.

```
proc sql;
    create view 
        v1 as
    select
        t2.c2, (final result)
        t1.c10, (not relevant to problem)
        SUM(t1.c11) (not relevant to problem)
    from 
        _outres.table1 t1
    left join
        _outres.table2 t2
    on 
        t1.c1=t2.c1 (comparing the tables)
    where
        t1.c10= "criteria"
    group by
        t2.c2,
        t1.c10
    ;run;quit;
```

If it was Excel, I would solve it like this:

```
Table 1
column 1
A
A
A
B
B
C
C

Table 2
Column 1    column 2
A           AA
B           BB
C           CC
```

=vlookup(table 1 column1, table 2, 2, false)

```
Result:
Table 1
column 1
AA
AA
AA
BB
BB
CC
CC
```

------------------ EDITED -----------------

@DCR, this was the code I used to test, based on your reply. I made some small changes to reflect better my data and tables. This worked as expected, but I failed to translate this to my original code.

```
data tttttt1;
input col1 $ col11 col10 $;
datalines;
A           10           critA
A           12           critA
A           13           critA
A           13           critB
B           11           critA
B           41           critA
B           19           critA
C           20           critA
C           55           critA

;
run;


data tttttt2;
input col1 $ col2 $ ;
datalines;
A           AA
B           BB
C           CC
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
     create table tttttt3 as
            select  b.col2, SUM(a.col11), a.col10
                from (select * from tttttt1) as a
                left join (select * from tttttt2) as b
                    on a.col1 = b.col1
            where a.col10 = "critA"
            group by b.col2, a.col10
;quit;
```

Expected and result were the same:

```
AA  35  critA
BB  71  critA
CC  75  critA
```

Comment: I don't use SAS so I cant give an answer.  However it does appear that vlookup returns a single result where join will return all matches causing duplication.  In TSQL I might do the join and use Row_Number and maybe Rank window functions to return only the first match.  Maybe search for Row_Number in SAS.

Comment: Can you give an example of the "cartesian product" output you're getting? The sql you've written should do generally the same thing you've sketched out below, however since you're using SUM and GROUP BY, the duplicate rows will be collapsed into one, summing t1.c11. Since you said t1 has duplicate rows, this is probably not what you want?

Comment: Your code looks fine. What problem are you having?

Comment: You mention you want to substitute data in `T1` with data from `T2`. Your query, however, does only add a new field (`T2.C2`) to the result. Substituting would mean you replace the values in `T1.C2` with the value from `T2.C2`, if there is a match. Is this what you wanted to do?
Otherwise: code looks fine, as long as `T2.C1` has (as you see), has only unique values. A `distinct` after select should be obsolete, since you are grouping over all fields that are not sums.

Comment: In case you really wanted a substitute, try replacing `T2.C2` with `coalesce(T2.C2, T1.C2)`

Comment: Martin Dreher, you are right, I want to substitute data from T1 with data from T2. T1 has all columns I need in my output, except by this one column (in the example code, I named it as t1.c1). For this column, I'd like to substitute the data with t2.c2 data, using t2.c1 as key. Exactly like I would do with Excel's vlookup function. About coalesce function, t1 and t2 have different sizes. t1 has around 1.8 million lines, t2 has around 1 housand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

Thanks everyone, all the answers, they gave me some insight.

@nvioli and @DCR gave me a huge insight. I was working to understand the cartesian product I was generating. I counted the lines and found the same amount of lines in the result compared to original t1 table. But the summed values were clearly wrong. So I understood that, somehow, my code was inserting the total sum in each line instead of the subtotals of "group by".

I solved it with the easiest solution possible: I splitted the view in two different views. The first one would group and sum, because na older version of this code was doing it correctly. The second view would only left join and change data in a simple select. Final code is something like this (simplified version, as the original example):

```
/*view to group and sum columns from t1*/
proc sql;
    create view 
        v1 as
    select
        t1.c1, (column that will be substitute later)
        t1.c10, (not relevant to problem, only to show the "criteria"/group by)
        SUM(t1.c11) (not relevant to problem, only to show sum)
    from 
        _outres.table1 t1
    where
        t1.c10= "criteria"
    group by
        t1.c1,
        t1.c10
    ;quit;run;
```

After that:

```
/*view to substitute the desired column from t1 (now v1) */
proc sql;
    create view 
        v2 as
select
        t2.c2, (column with new data)
        t1.c10, (now already grouped)
        Sum_of_t1.c11 (now already summed)
from 
    v1 
left join
    t2
on
    v1.c1 = t2.c1 (comparing view from t1 with t2)
;quit;run;
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS has a unique feature in the form of **custom formats**.  A format maps a source value to a target value, much in the way of VLOOKUP.

A format is associated with a variable by using the `FORMAT` statement.

```
proc format;
  value $MyFormat
  'A' = 'AA'
  'B' = 'BB'
  'C' = 'CC'
  ;
run;

data have;
  input col1 $ @@; 
  col1_formatted_value = put(col1,$MyFormat.); * typically don't have to do this;
  datalines;
  A A A B B C C D D A
run;

proc print data=have;
  title "Data rendered per attributes associated with variables in data set metadata";
run;
proc print data=have;
  title "col1 Format applied at step time";
  format col1 $MyFormat.;
run;

* col1 format attribute saved with data set;
data have2;
  input col1 $ @@; 
  format col1 $MyFormat.;
  datalines;
  A A A B B C C D D A
run;

proc print data=have2;
  title "Data rendered per format attributes associated with variables (in data set metadata)";
run;
```

SAS Formats can also be constructed directly from data:

```
data formatMappingData;
input source $ target $;
fmtname = "$MyFormatFromData";
start = source;
label = target;
datalines;
A AA!
B BB!
C CC!
;
run;

proc format cntlin=formatMappingData;
run;

proc print data=have2;
  title "Data rendered per format attributes associated with variables (in data set metadata)";
  format col1 $MyFormatFromData.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty new to SAS, that's why I'm using SQL. I couldn't understand how to use data from table 2. When I used A to AA as example, I think I was not clear enough. It's not converting A to AA, a simple format issue. It's changing from apple to banana. And table 2 has only 2 columns, but tons of lines, I can't hardcode it.

Comment: You can generate a format from data.  You will just need to recreate it if the lookup table changes.  Normally lookup tables are pretty static.  It is the actual data that might change frequently.

Comment: While Richard is right that formats can be used for lookups (and this can be useful for performance), in this case the SQL solution should have worked as well, and learning to work with formats may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for a left join using proc sql.  Try the following:

```
data t1;
input col1 $ ;
datalines;
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
;
run;

data t2;
input col1 $ col2 $ ;
datalines;
A           AA
B           BB
C           CC
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
     create table t3 as
            select b.col2
                  from (select * from t1) as a
             left join (select * from t2) as b
             on a.col1 = b.col1;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this code is similar to mine, didn't work.

Comment: That's odd, I ran on SAS9.4 and it produced the results you listed. Show me what you tried and what results did you get.

Comment: Let me fair in this comment: Your code Works perfectly in your example. I made some changes to reflect better my OP data and tables. Edited the OP to introduce what I did. But I failed in implemente these codes. But I managed to find another solution and I learned now a better way to code it due to your reply. Many thanks.